# Execute elite el exe failed

Tags: c, dongle, c51

I'm using elite el el net version. We buy this dongle from senselock europa but there is not e4nmgr.exe in our dongle trial kit.Where I can find it. I download sdk from [this](http://forum.senselock.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4859&sid=93e7ca9b3ef30d723e3a5354b415b7ab) forum but it is not work because it is russich.

And I write codes in tutorial like below. and write uvision codes for dongle but when ı want to run it. it give an error "Execute elite el exe failed".Is this about e4nmgr.exe or different ı use mt library and ı work in 64 bit.

Is net version dongles can not support execution.

This is my main code:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "sense4.h"

/*bubble sort function removed. Add Elite EL invoking code. */
void call_sense4(char *, unsigned char *, int);

/*main procedure*/
void main()
{
    unsigned char test[] = { 4,3,8,2,9,7,1,5,0,6 };
    int len = sizeof(test);
    int i;

    call_sense4("d001", test, len);

    printf("result:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", test[i]);
    }


    _getch();
}

void call_sense4(char *fid, unsigned char *buff, int len)
{
    SENSE4_CONTEXT ctx = { 0 };
    SENSE4_CONTEXT *pctx = NULL;
    unsigned long size = 0;
    unsigned long ret = 0;

    S4Enum(pctx, &size);
    if (size == 0)
    {
        printf("Elite EL not found!\n");
        return;
    }

    pctx = (SENSE4_CONTEXT *)malloc(size);
    if (pctx == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory!\n");
        return;
    }

    ret = S4Enum(pctx, &size);
    if (ret != S4_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Enumerate Elite EL error!\n");
        free(pctx);
        return;
    }

    memcpy(&ctx, pctx, sizeof(SENSE4_CONTEXT));
    free(pctx);
    pctx = NULL;

    ret = S4Open(&ctx);
    if (ret != S4_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Open Elite EL failed!\n");
        return;
    }

    ret = S4ChangeDir(&ctx, "\\");
    if (ret != S4_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("No root directory found!\n");
        S4Close(&ctx);
        return;
    }

    ret = S4VerifyPin(&ctx, "12345678", 8, S4_USER_PIN);
    if (ret != S4_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Verify user PIN failed!\n");
        S4Close(&ctx);
        return;
    }

    ret = S4Execute(&ctx, fid, buff, len, buff, len, &size);
    if (ret != S4_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Execute Elite EL exe failed!\n");
        S4Close(&ctx);
        return;
    }

    S4Close(&ctx);

    return;
}
```

and this is my code for usb I use uvision c51 for below code.

```
#include "ses_v3.h"

void bubble_sort(unsigned char *p, int len)
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned char tmp;
    for (i=0; i<len-1; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<len-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (p[j] < p[j+1])
            {
                tmp = p[j];
                p[j] = p[j+1];
                p[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
/*Senselock ELmain procedure*/
void main()
{
    unsigned char *test = pbInBuff;
    int len = bInLen;
    bubble_sort(test, len);
    _set_response(len,test);
    _exit();
}
```

Comment: Have You tried contacting official support?

Comment: Yes but they are not answered yet.